# Apache camel : how to split sql result into groups

Tags: oracle, apache-camel

**How to split result of sql query in apache camel ?** Let`s say you will get 1000 rows as result and you want to process them not one by one but in groups e.g. 1 group = 10 rows.

following Apache Camel configuration looks for record with given RECORD_ID, in the next step Camel "splitter" iterates result of first query and runs another query.

For example if we get 1000 rows as result of query *db.query.select.active.record* then second query *db.query.select.compute.statistics* will run 1000x (for each row of previous query). As performance is not optimal, we would like to create group of RECORD_IDs For example : first query would return 1000 rows, we would split that into 100 groups (10 rows per group) and then we could run query only 100x.

Sample configuration :

```
<route>
    <from uri="seda:retrieveAlphaData" />
    <process ref="alphaResourceInitializer"/>
    <to uri="sql:{{db.query.select.active.record}}" />
    <camel:split>
        <camel:simple>${in.body}</camel:simple>
        <camel:setHeader headerName="recordId">
            <camel:simple>${in.body[RECORD_ID]}</camel:simple>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <setBody>
            <simple>${in.body[RECORD_NAME]}</simple>
        </setBody>
        <to uri="sql:{{db.query.select.compute.statistics}}" />
        <process ref="allActiveRecordDataFormatTransformer" />
        <camel:marshal ref="json" />
        <to uri="bean:activeRecordSdbPersister?method=processIt" />
    </camel:split>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the route, after "sql:{{db.query.select.active.record}}"? the result can be sent to SEDA endpoint and you can configure 10 SEDA consumers which will process 10 records concurrently